# ValueError while exporting data to excel for a django application

Tags: python, django, excel

I am trying to write some code to export some data from the website to excel sheet. This is part of me trying to rewrite the entire website using Django. Below is the script I wrote for the export.

```
def national_proposal_export_xlsx(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    import openpyxl
    from openpyxl.cell import get_column_letter
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=conference_proposals_export.xlsx'
    wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
    ws = wb.get_active_sheet()
    ws.title = "Conference_proposals"

    row_num = 0

    columns = [
        (u"Master", 15),
        (u"Code", 15),
        (u"Title", 70),
        (u"Begin Time", 15),
        (u"End Time", 15),
        (u"Event type", 15),
        (u"Status", 15),
        # (u"Published", 15),
        # (u"Up to date", 15),
    ]

    for col_num in range(len(columns)):
        c = ws.cell(row=row_num + 1, column=col_num + 1)
        c.value = columns[col_num][0]
        # c.style.font.bold = True
        ws.column_dimensions[get_column_letter(col_num+1)].width = columns[col_num][1]

    for obj in queryset:
        row_num += 1
        row = [
            obj.master,
            obj.code,
            obj.title,
            obj.begin_time,
            obj.end_time,
            obj.event_type,
            obj.status,
            # obj.published,
            # obj.up_to_date,
        ]

        for col_num in range(len(row)):
            c = ws.cell(row=row_num + 1, column=col_num + 1)
            c.value = row[col_num]
            c.style.alignment.wrap_text = True

    wb.save(response)
    return response
```

But for some reason I am getting the following error:

`ValueError at /admin/events/nationalconferenceproposal/
Cannot convert 9000476 | TEST SESSION 001 (draft) to Excel
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/events/nationalconferenceproposal/
Django Version: 1.7.3
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:

Cannot convert 9000476 | TEST SESSION 001 (draft) to Excel
Exception Location: /Users/dthota/Code/venvs/planning/lib/python3.4/site-packages/openpyxl/cell/cell.py in _bind_value, line 217
Python Executable:  /Users/dthota/Code/venvs/planning/bin/python
Python Version: 3.4.3`

Its says the error is with `c.value = row[col_num]` in the last for loop. But I can't understand it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is an old question, but I was just struggling with a similar issue. For me the solution was to cast the row[col_num] to string:

```
c.value = str(row[col_num])
```

Note that the data is then saved as text on the excel workbook so you might need something else if you want to do calculations etc. with the data.